# Tapping the battery from an UPS to feed low voltage devices

Tags: power-supply, batteries, ups

My UPS powers one 120V AC device and a whole bunch of small 'bricks' that end up rectifying things down to 5-12V DC. Instead of using the 'bricks', my idea is to tap the battery directly, and use DC-DC converters to get down to desired voltage. 
  Would this result in better efficiency? Would it even work? Any potential pitfalls?

Answer (score 6):

Most small UPSes are so-called "off-line" systems.  When grid power is live, they feed input AC directly through to the output.  In parallel, they trickle-charge the batteries.  When grid power fails, they quickly switch to inverter mode, where the batteries are discharged into an DC->AC inverter to power the downstream loads.

For your application, an off-line UPS wouldn't work for a number of reasons, with the primary risk being that the trickle charger can't keep up with a full load (now DC).

In contrast, an "on-line" UPS feeds all power through the battery bus, such that it's all converted to DC, then re-inverted to AC.  On power-loss, the AC->DC front end simply powers down and the DC-AC inverter continues to operate off batteries.  This *might* work for your application, though it's impossible to determine if the ripple on the DC bus would play nicely with your loads.

As to efficiency, the efficiency of the "on-line" UPS is less than that of an "off-line" UPS, as there is an extra AC->DC->AC conversion step at all times.  Let's look at the normal power flow through each type of system:

Off-line, grid live:
AC->AC(pass-thru)->DC(brick)

On-line, grid live:
AC->DC(battery)->AC->DC(brick)

Direct battery tap - on-line, grid live:
AC->DC(battery)->AC(DC/DC converter)->DC(DC/DC converter)->DC(load power)

To sum up, I'd expect the grid-live efficiency of an off-line UPS running DC/DC converters to run power bricks to be less efficient than an on-line UPS powering loads directly.